# IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Currently I am trying to deal with a strange Exception when opening a BluetoothSocket on my Nexus 7 (2012), with Android 4.3 (Build JWR66Y, I guess the second 4.3 update). I have seen some related postings (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648373/bluetoothsocket-connect-throwing-exception-read-failed), but none seems to provide a workaround for this issue. Also, as suggested in these threads, re-pairing does not help, and constantly trying to connect (through a stupid loop) also has no effect.

I am dealing with an embedded device (a noname OBD-II car adapter, similar to http://images04.olx.com/ui/15/53/76/1316534072_254254776_2-OBD-II-BLUTOOTH-ADAPTERSCLEAR-CHECK-ENGINE-LIGHTS-WITH-YOUR-PHONE-Oceanside.jpg). My Android 2.3.7 phone does not have any issues connecting, and the Xperia of a colleague (Android 4.1.2) also works. Another Google Nexus (I dont know if 'One' or 'S', but not '4') also fails with Android 4.3.

Here is the Snippet of the connection establishment. It is running in its own Thread, created within a Service.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private static final UUID EMBEDDED_BOARD_SPP = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
    private boolean secure;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private List<UUID> uuidCandidates;
    private int candidate;
    protected boolean started;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        logger.info("initiliasing connection to device "+device.getName() +" / "+ device.getAddress());
        adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.secure = secure;
        this.device = device;

        setName("BluetoothConnectThread");

        if (!startQueryingForUUIDs()) {
            this.uuidCandidates = Collections.singletonList(EMBEDDED_BOARD_SPP);
            this.start();
        } else{
            logger.info("Using UUID discovery mechanism.");
        }
        /*
         * it will start upon the broadcast receive otherwise
         */
    }

    private boolean startQueryingForUUIDs() {
        Class<?> cl = BluetoothDevice.class;

        Class<?>[] par = {};
        Method fetchUuidsWithSdpMethod;
        try {
            fetchUuidsWithSdpMethod = cl.getMethod("fetchUuidsWithSdp", par);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        Object[] args = {};
        try {
            BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    BluetoothDevice deviceExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");
                    Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");

                    uuidCandidates = new ArrayList<UUID>();
                    for (Parcelable uuid : uuidExtra) {
                        uuidCandidates.add(UUID.fromString(uuid.toString()));
                    }

                    synchronized (ConnectThread.this) {
                        if (!ConnectThread.this.started) {
                            ConnectThread.this.start();
                            ConnectThread.this.started = true;
                            unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }

                    }
                }

            };
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.bleutooth.device.action.UUID"));
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID"));

            fetchUuidsWithSdpMethod.invoke(device, args);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }           

        return true;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean success = false;
        while (selectSocket()) {

            if (bluetoothSocket == null) {
                logger.warn("Socket is null! Cancelling!");
                deviceDisconnected();
                openTroubleshootingActivity(TroubleshootingActivity.BLUETOOTH_EXCEPTION);
            }

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
                break;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    shutdownSocket();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    logger.warn(e2.getMessage(), e2);
                }
            }
        }

        if (success) {
            deviceConnected();
        } else {
            deviceDisconnected();
            openTroubleshootingActivity(TroubleshootingActivity.BLUETOOTH_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    private boolean selectSocket() {
        if (candidate >= uuidCandidates.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        BluetoothSocket tmp;
        UUID uuid = uuidCandidates.get(candidate++);
        logger.info("Attempting to connect to SDP "+ uuid);
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        uuid);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        uuid);
            }
            bluetoothSocket = tmp;
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage() ,e);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

The code is failing at `bluetoothSocket.connect()`. I am getting a `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1`. This is the corresponding source at GitHub: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.3_r2/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java#L504
Its called through readInt(), called from https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.3_r2/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java#L319

Some metadata dump of the used socket resulted in the following information. These are exactly the same on Nexus 7 and my 2.3.7 phone.

```
Bluetooth Device 'OBDII'
Address: 11:22:33:DD:EE:FF
Bond state: 12 (bonded)
Type: 1
Class major version: 7936
Class minor version: 7936
Class Contents: 0
Contents: 0
```

I have some other OBD-II adapters (more expansives) and they all work. Is there any chance, that I am missing something or might this be a bug in Android?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I have finally found a workaround. The magic is hidden under the hood of the `BluetoothDevice` class (see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.3_r2/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#L1037).

Now, when I receive that exception, I instantiate a fallback `BluetoothSocket`, similar to the source code below. As you can see, invoking the hidden method `createRfcommSocket` via reflections. I have no clue why this method is hidden. The source code defines it as `public` though...

```
Class<?> clazz = tmp.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[] {Integer.TYPE};

Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1)};

fallbackSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(tmp.getRemoteDevice(), params);
fallbackSocket.connect();
```

`connect()` then does not fail any longer. I have experienced a few issues still. Basically, this sometimes blocks and fails. Rebooting the SPP-Device (plug off / plug in) helps in such cases. Sometimes I also get another Pairing request after `connect()` even when the device is already bonded.

UPDATE:

here is a complete class, containing some nested classes. for a real implementation these could be held as seperate classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothConnector {

    private BluetoothSocketWrapper bluetoothSocket;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private boolean secure;
    private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
    private List<UUID> uuidCandidates;
    private int candidate;


    /**
     * @param device the device
     * @param secure if connection should be done via a secure socket
     * @param adapter the Android BT adapter
     * @param uuidCandidates a list of UUIDs. if null or empty, the Serial PP id is used
     */
    public BluetoothConnector(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure, BluetoothAdapter adapter,
            List<UUID> uuidCandidates) {
        this.device = device;
        this.secure = secure;
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.uuidCandidates = uuidCandidates;

        if (this.uuidCandidates == null || this.uuidCandidates.isEmpty()) {
            this.uuidCandidates = new ArrayList<UUID>();
            this.uuidCandidates.add(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        }
    }

    public BluetoothSocketWrapper connect() throws IOException {
        boolean success = false;
        while (selectSocket()) {
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //try the fallback
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = new FallbackBluetoothSocket(bluetoothSocket.getUnderlyingSocket());
                    Thread.sleep(500);                  
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    success = true;
                    break;  
                } catch (FallbackException e1) {
                    Log.w("BT", "Could not initialize FallbackBluetoothSocket classes.", e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    Log.w("BT", e1.getMessage(), e1);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.w("BT", "Fallback failed. Cancelling.", e1);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!success) {
            throw new IOException("Could not connect to device: "+ device.getAddress());
        }

        return bluetoothSocket;
    }

    private boolean selectSocket() throws IOException {
        if (candidate >= uuidCandidates.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        BluetoothSocket tmp;
        UUID uuid = uuidCandidates.get(candidate++);

        Log.i("BT", "Attempting to connect to Protocol: "+ uuid);
        if (secure) {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } else {
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        }
        bluetoothSocket = new NativeBluetoothSocket(tmp);

        return true;
    }

    public static interface BluetoothSocketWrapper {

        InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException;

        OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException;

        String getRemoteDeviceName();

        void connect() throws IOException;

        String getRemoteDeviceAddress();

        void close() throws IOException;

        BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket();

    }


    public static class NativeBluetoothSocket implements BluetoothSocketWrapper {

        private BluetoothSocket socket;

        public NativeBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket tmp) {
            this.socket = tmp;
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return socket.getInputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return socket.getOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public String getRemoteDeviceName() {
            return socket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
        }

        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {
            socket.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public String getRemoteDeviceAddress() {
            return socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            socket.close();
        }

        @Override
        public BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket() {
            return socket;
        }

    }

    public class FallbackBluetoothSocket extends NativeBluetoothSocket {

        private BluetoothSocket fallbackSocket;

        public FallbackBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket tmp) throws FallbackException {
            super(tmp);
            try
            {
              Class<?> clazz = tmp.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
              Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[] {Integer.TYPE};
              Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
              Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1)};
              fallbackSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(tmp.getRemoteDevice(), params);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new FallbackException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return fallbackSocket.getInputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return fallbackSocket.getOutputStream();
        }


        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {
            fallbackSocket.connect();
        }


        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            fallbackSocket.close();
        }

    }

    public static class FallbackException extends Exception {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public FallbackException(Exception e) {
            super(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to connect to multiple bluetooth devices, remember that you need to increase the number of the channel. Valid channels are 1-30

Comment: Hi, How did you use this code for connection, Can you please tell  me

Comment: Thank you @matthes.. you solved my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29143695/1994950 I have mentioned your answer there

Comment: @matthes, How to use the BluetoothConnector class? Does it replace the BluetoothSocket class?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for Explanation, I am very new to bluetooth as i am trying this in my code, but its showing IOException: read failed, socket might closed at @fallbackSocket.connect(); Please help me out. If possible can you send me code for sender and receiver end.

Comment: @matthes Sorry to say but even your solution of using the fallback has not Solved my problem.
Getting below Error.
`Fallback failed. Cancelling.
java.io.IOException: Connection refused`

Please help.

Comment: @matthes "SPP-Device (plug off / plug in) helps in such cases. " . The on/off statement is the most underrated in the world. I just wasted 3 hours and all I had to do was turn it on and off -_-

Comment: When I try to write int the BluetoothSocketWrapper getOutputStream(), I get the java.io.IOException: socket closed exception.

Comment: @matthes : How to use this BluetoothConnector class ?

Comment: @matthes, big thanks for this idea (and the source), I don't know how you came up with this idea but you are awsome. Working as it should :) By the way - "normal" way of setting up bluetooth was working unitll I upgraded project from API 21 to 24. Maybe this hint shines some light on what exactly is going on here...

Comment: This also works for me but I would like to ask, if I want to close the connection from another method, should I call the constructor again?

Comment: For those if this solution is not working try to change 1 with 2. I replaced
Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1)};
with:
Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(2)};
and it is working now.

Comment: Thankx @UmamaKhalid changing value from 1 with 2 is working now. Saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 112):

well, i had the same problem with my code, and it's because since android 4.2 bluetooth stack has changed. so my code was running fine on devices with android < 4.2 , on the other devices i was getting the famous exception **"read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"**

The problem is with the `socket.mPort` parameter. When you create your socket using `socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);` , the `mPort` gets integer value "**-1**", and this value seems doesn't work for android >=4.2 , so you need to set it to "**1**". The bad news is that `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` only accepts UUID as parameter and not `mPort` so we have to use other aproach. The answer posted by **@matthes** also worked for me, but i simplified it: `socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,1);`. We need to use both socket attribs , the second one as a fallback.

So the code is (for connecting to a SPP on an ELM327 device):

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        SharedPreferences prefs_btdev = getSharedPreferences("btdev", 0);
        String btdevaddr=prefs_btdev.getString("btdevaddr","?");

        if (btdevaddr != "?")
        {
            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btdevaddr);

            UUID SERIAL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // bluetooth serial port service
            //UUID SERIAL_UUID = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid(); //if you don't know the UUID of the bluetooth device service, you can get it like this from android cache

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("","Error creating socket");}

            try {
                socket.connect();
                Log.e("","Connected");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("",e.getMessage());
                try {
                    Log.e("","trying fallback...");

                    socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,1);
                    socket.connect();

                    Log.e("","Connected");
                }
             catch (Exception e2) {
                 Log.e("", "Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection!");
              }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("","BT device not selected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: for moderators: since you deleted my previous answer for no reason, i post it again.

Comment: thanks George for the insights on the `mPort` parameter! imho the workflow stays the same, I just wrapped things with some classes implementing an interface.

Comment: yes, i already said your solution was good, but i wanted to make people understand why it needs to use this approach starting with android 4.2

Comment: It did not work. :( I used it in a Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2) acting as server, and a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3) as client, having previously discovered each other. Changing roles does not work either.

Comment: well, be more precise , what error do you have? first of all you don't need this fallback sollution since you are in android 4.1 , what bluetooth service are you using, my example is for SPP

Comment: SPP = Serial Port Profile (that emulates a serial port over bluetooth) and ELM327 is a bluetooth <-> obd car device , google it.

Comment: @GeorgeDima..
Can you give an insight on why this approach works? 
Also why the socket.connect() fails, I wish I know how the person who thought and found the first solution would have thought and reached this answer.

Comment: i know it's because since android 4.2 bluetooth stack has changed, i'm not an android os creator to know more...

Comment: @GeorgeDima... On fallback why doses the reflection method work? Please provide me with more information if possible.

Comment: i already explained in my post! (the mPort gets integer value "-1", and this value seems doesn't work for android >=4.2 , so you need to set it to "1") , so the fallback methods enables you to set mport to 1 vs the default method with sets it to -1.

Comment: Its worked for me after changed the port value from 1 to 2.please look at this code.                                                                            socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,2);
 socket.connect();

Comment: Thanks for All comments above and posted answer.  1 was not working for me.. socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,2); socket.connect();..  Its showing connected now. Can you please help me with the receiver end means how i will receive data.

Comment: how do you do the fallback if you originally got the socket via a serversocket?

Comment: Hi george , i have tried with the both values 1 and 2 but still getting the same exception  "read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1" . . .plz help me out

Comment: The above solution still gives the same error. And as @NirmalPrajapat tried both values I Still see same behavior. Even in Android 7.0. Is this indication that Android is just broken? Or is it that the two dozen or so different device I have tried are all broken?

Comment: I get `NullPointerException` on `socket.connect()` while trying to implement this

Answer (score 19):

First, if you need to talk to a bluetooth 2.x device, [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord/p/Java.Util.UUID/) states that :

> Hint: If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using
>   the **well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB**. However
>   if you are connecting to an Android peer then please generate your own
>   unique UUID.

I didn't think that it would work, but only by replacing the UUID with `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` it works. However, this code seems to handle the problem of SDK version, and you can just replace the function `device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mMyUuid);` with `tmp = createBluetoothSocket(mmDevice);` after defining the following method :

```
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device)
    throws IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, mMyUuid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
    }
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mMyUuid);
}
```

The source code isn't mine, but comes from [this website](http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/).

Comment: That solved almost 2 days of work... *thankful sigh* ...Without this UUID the socket would close immediately and fail without further explanation.

Comment: thank you very much for help MY UUID is alphanumeric and i am trying to connect HC-5 and my bluetooth showing connection fail but when i used this solution my problem solve. thank you again

Answer (score 9):

I had the same symptoms as described here. I could connect once to a bluetooth printer but subsequent connects failed with "socket closed" no matter what I did.

I found it a bit strange that the workarounds described here would be necessary. After going through my code I found that I had forgot to close the socket's InputStream and OutputSteram and not terminated the ConnectedThreads properly.

The ConnectedThread I use is the same as in the example here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Note that ConnectThread and ConnectedThread are two different classes.

Whatever class that starts the ConnectedThread must call interrupt() and cancel() on the thread.
I added mmInStream.close() and mmOutStream.close() in the ConnectedTread.cancel() method.

After closing the threads/streams/sockets properly I could create new sockets without any problem.

Comment: Thanks, was having the same issue, just now I figured that I hadn't closed the stream and the connection...

Comment: tried all of the above scenarios , (except for removing other paired devices causes well that really isn't a solution found that yes ... this normally only happens when the input streams and sockets don't get closed properly.....!!

Answer (score 9):

On newer versions of Android, I was receiving this error because the adapter was still discovering when I attempted to connect to the socket. Even though I called the cancelDiscovery method on the Bluetooth adapter, I had to wait until the callback to the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method was called with the action BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.

Once I waited for the adapter to stop discovery, then the connect call on the socket succeeded.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I have actually found the problem.

The most people who try to make a connection using `socket.Connect();` get an exception called `Java.IO.IOException: read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1`.

In some cases it also depends on your Bluetooth device, because there are two different types of Bluetooth, namely BLE (low energy) and Classic.

If you want to check the type of your Bluetooth device is, here's the code:

```
        String checkType;
        var listDevices = BluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices;
        if (listDevices.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var btDevice in listDevices)
            {
                if(btDevice.Name == "MOCUTE-032_B52-CA7E")
                {
                    checkType = btDevice.Type.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(checkType);
                }
            }
        }
```

I've been trying for days to solve the problem, but since today I have found the problem. The solution from @matthes has unfortunately still a few issues as he said already, but here's my solution.

At the moment I work in Xamarin Android, but this should also work for other platforms.

**SOLUTION**

If there is more than one paired device, then you should remove the other paired devices. So keep only the one that you want to connect (see the right image).

[image]
[image]

In the left image you see that I have two paired devices, namely "MOCUTE-032_B52-CA7E" and "Blue Easy". That's the issue, but I have no idea why that problem occurs. Maybe the Bluetooth protocol is trying to get some information from another Bluetooth device.

However, the `socket.Connect();` works great right now, without any problems. So I just wanted to share this, because that error is really annoying.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked on the one device where I encounter this problem, which only occurs for me on a 5.0 phone, and even then only when I'm first enabling BT, then opening a connection. If BT were already on, no connection problem! It doesn't occur on devices with a later version of Android, suggesting the devs noticed the bug & fixed it, but the Android BT page breathes not a word about it. But your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In case somebody is having issues with Kotlin, I had to follow the accepted answer with some variations:

```
fun print(view: View, text: String) {
    var adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    var pairedDevices = adapter.getBondedDevices()
    var uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    if (pairedDevices.size > 0) {
        for (device in pairedDevices) {
            var s = device.name
            if (device.getName().equals(printerName, ignoreCase = true)) {
                Thread {
                    var socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
                    var clazz = socket.remoteDevice.javaClass
                    var paramTypes = arrayOf<Class<*>>(Integer.TYPE)
                    var m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", *paramTypes)
                    var fallbackSocket = m.invoke(socket.remoteDevice, Integer.valueOf(1)) as BluetoothSocket
                    try {
                        fallbackSocket.connect()
                        var stream = fallbackSocket.outputStream
                        stream.write(text.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        Snackbar.make(view, "An error occurred", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }.start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

You put
`registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.bleutooth.device.action.UUID"));`
with "bluetooth" spelled "bleutooth".

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth devices can operate in both classic and LE mode at the same time. Sometimes they use a different MAC address depending on which way you are connecting. Calling `socket.connect()` is using Bluetooth Classic, so you have to make sure the device you got when you scanned was really a classic device.

It's easy to filter for only Classic devices, however:

`if(BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE == device.getType()){
    //socket.connect()
}`

Without this check, it's a race condition as to whether a hybrid scan will give you the Classic device or the BLE device first. It may appear as intermittent inability to connect, or as certain devices being able to connect reliably while others seemingly never can.

Answer (score 1):

i also faced with this problem,you could solve it in 2 ways , as mentioned earlier use reflection to create the socket
Second one is, 
client is looking for a server with given UUID and if your server isn't running parallel to client then this happens.
Create a server with given client UUID and then listen and accept the client from server side.It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Even i had the same problem ,finally understand my issue , i was trying to connect from (out of range) Bluetooth coverage range.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and fixed it by closing the input and output streams before closing the socket. Now I can disconnect and connect again with no issues.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039807/5688612

In Kotlin:

```
fun disconnect() {
    bluetoothSocket.inputStream.close()
    bluetoothSocket.outputStream.close()
    bluetoothSocket.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If another part of your code has already made a connection with the same socket and UUID, you get this error.

Comment: but if I disconnected from this socket and trying to connect again?

Comment: Sure it would work, but in my case, it required an architecture change, as I didn't "own" the other module!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and the solution was to use the special magic GUID.

```
            val id: UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB") // Any other GUID doesn't work.
            val device: BluetoothDevice = bta!!.bondedDevices.first { z -> z.name == deviceName }

            bts = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(id) // mPort is -1
            bts?.connect()
            // Start processing thread.
```

I suspect that these are the UUIDs that work:

```
var did: Array<ParcelUuid?> = device.uuids
```

However, I have not tried them all.

Comment: Even I'm using same UUID. But didn't helped me. Does this supports only for connecting to Classic bluetooth devices(not BLE)? What I have to do to connect to BLE devices using Xamarin.Forms. Posted here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371859/how-to-connect-to-another-device-through-bluetooth-and-send-some-data-and-receiv]

Comment: I'm using classic Bluetooth; BLE is rubbish.

Answer (score -2):

By adding filter action my problem resolved

```
 // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score -4):

I have also receive the same `IOException`, but I find the Android system demo: "BluetoothChat" project is worked. I determined the problem is the UUID.

So i replace my `UUID.fromString("00001001-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")` to `UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66")` and it worked most scene,only sometimes need to restart the Bluetooth device;