# getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback for Android Nexus 5

Tags: android-bluetooth, connection-timeout, spp

I am going to implemenet the module for sending commands from my Android smartphone to HC-06 via BLuetooth. WHen it comes to the execution , it show s the following exception and find no clue for the error message as title . Would you please tell the way to modifiy ?

Exception Log Message :

```
 07-29 13:51:37.701: W/BluetoothAdapter(1928): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
    07-29 13:51:37.711: D/BluetoothSocket(1928): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[51]}
    07-29 13:51:42.831: W/System.err(1928): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    07-29 13:51:42.831: W/System.err(1928):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:505)
    07-29 13:51:42.831: W/System.err(1928):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:516)
    07-29 13:51:42.831: W/System.err(1928):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:320)
    07-29 13:51:42.831: W/System.err(1928):     at com.luugiathuy.apps.remotebluetooth.BluetoothCommandService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothCommandService.java:260)
    07-29 13:51:42.831: D/BluetoothCommandService(1928): setState() 2 -> 1
```

The below is my code

```
public class BluetoothCommandService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothCommandService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Unique UUID for this application
   // private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
//    private BluetoothDevice mSavedDevice;
//    private int mConnectionLostCount;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    // Constants that indicate command to computer
    public static final int EXIT_CMD = -1;
    public static final int VOL_UP = 1;
    public static final int VOL_DOWN = 2;
    public static final int MOUSE_MOVE = 3;

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothCommandService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        //mConnectionLostCount = 0;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // save connected device
        //mSavedDevice = device;
        // reset connection lost count
        //mConnectionLostCount = 0;

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    public void write(int out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
//        mConnectionLostCount++;
//        if (mConnectionLostCount < 3) {
//          // Send a reconnect message back to the Activity
//          Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_TOAST);
//          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//          bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.TOAST, "Device connection was lost. Reconnecting...");
//          msg.setData(bundle);
//          mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
//          
//          connect(mSavedDevice);      
//        } else {
            setState(STATE_LISTEN);
            // Send a failure message back to the Activity
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
//        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothCommandService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    int bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                mmOutStream.flush();
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
//                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
//                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void write(int out) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(out);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
//                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
//                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(EXIT_CMD);
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Activity`

```
public class RemoteBluetooth extends Activity {

    // Layout view
    private TextView mTitle;

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

    // Key names received from the BluetoothCommandService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    // Member object for Bluetooth Command Service
    private BluetoothCommandService mCommandService = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up the window layout
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        // Set up the custom title
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
        mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupCommand() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        // otherwise set up the command service
        else {
            if (mCommandService==null)
                setupCommand();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mCommandService != null) {
            if (mCommandService.getState() == BluetoothCommandService.STATE_NONE) {
                mCommandService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupCommand() {
        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mCommandService = new BluetoothCommandService(this, mHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mCommandService != null)
            mCommandService.stop();
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                    mTitle.append("HC-06");
                    break;
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_NONE:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                String address = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address);
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                mCommandService.connect(device);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupCommand();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

            String blinkCommand = "&$V00X77V0" ;
            String empty = "";
            for (int i = 0 ; i < (100 - blinkCommand.length()) ; i ++){
                empty += "0";
            }
            String limiter = "\r\n";

            String fullCommand = blinkCommand +  empty + limiter;
            mCommandService.write(fullCommand.getBytes());
    //      mCommandService.write(BluetoothCommandService.VOL_UP);
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
            String blinkCommand = "&$V00X77V0" + "\r\n";
            mCommandService.write(blinkCommand.getBytes());
        //  mCommandService.write(BluetoothCommandService.VOL_DOWN);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

since android 4.2 , bluetooth stack changed, so i guess you are testing on android>=4.2 .

your problem is here `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);` . this socket creation method is not compatible starting with 4.2 , so you will need to use the fallback one after it fails : `tmp =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,1);`

Don't worry about `called with no BluetoothManagerCallback` being thrown, it doesn't matter.

So if you do it like this, it will work:

```
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("","Error creating socket");}

        try {
            socket.connect();
            Log.e("","Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("",e.getMessage());
            try {
                Log.e("","trying fallback...");

                socket =(BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device,1);
                socket.connect();

                Log.e("","Connected");
            }
```

also, i answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647197/1639215) more detailed, about a similar problem.