# SerialPort / Bluetooth support in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.UWP

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, serial-port, uwp

I'm making an app for Android and UWP that connects to a barcode scanner over bluetooth, but I'm really struggling getting the right lib or something because System.IO.Ports isn't available.

I also tried to implement both in some abstraction library, but it seems difficult. Is there someone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create different implementation for different platform.

For Android platform, there are some discussions, for example:

- [Xamarin forum question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30055/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-xamarin-android)
- [Connecting to a Bluetooth Scanner with Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685461/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-xamarin-android)

For Universal Windows Platform, the [Barcode Scanner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426649.aspx) API is the right thing we need to use. Please notice the Remark part in that document.

The official [Barcode scanner sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner) is a good demo for beginner.

Comment: Thank you for this, but as it uses the android bluetooth classes, i want something more event driven like a connected and disconnected event.

Comment: Can i use Plugin.Ble if i buy a bluetooth 4.0 scanner?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but... I am using this Nuget Package:
https://github.com/inthehand/32feet

It supports Classic Bletooth and Bluetooth BLE, and it works both on Android and iOS. The project is supported at this date and it is very well documented.