# Android tablet does not connect to Woosim printer?

Tags: android, printing

I have the following code for connecting my android application to [Woosim printer WSP-R240](http://www.woosim.com/english/bbs/message/message.view.do?boardId=4&messageId=321).

```
    String addressA = "74:F0:7D:E2:6A:DD";
    String addressB = "00:15:0E:E2:92:42";

    com.woosim.bt.WoosimPrinter woosim = new com.woosim.bt.WoosimPrinter();
    int result = woosim.BTConnection(addressA, false);

    if (result != 1)
    {
        result = woosim.BTConnection(addressB, false);
    }
```

I have 2 printers A and B. I want to print by B if A is switched off.

When I set the string `addressA` to a fake address, the woosim object connects to printer B successfully. But when `addressA` is the address of a **paired device** and it is switched off so the `result` is not 1, the woosim object does not connect to printer B.

What is wrong here?

I have tried using `SystemClock.sleep(5000);`, but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786701/779408

In that solution the hidden method `createRfcommSocket` is used