# android EDR connect timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need some help about android EDR connect.
I use EDR to connect device. But sometimes `socket.connect` throws an exception:

> read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Then I close bluetooth and reopen it. Connect will return success.

Comment: pls add your code or we can't help you.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143695/java-io-ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-or-timeout-read-ret-1-o

Comment: this is my code
`try{
 socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
 socket.connect();
}catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}`