# Send stream to already connected device over Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, stream, bluetooth-socket

I'll try to explain my problem as best possible, since my English is a little rusty.
I need to make an application to communicate via bluetooth (sending streams) to a device that has been already connected by the user.
I mean, I need to have a bluetoothSocket to do bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream ().

Is that possible?

I clarify that this is the only way I can think of, because I can't a connect two devices programmatically, I followed everything said in this post([IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3)) but I keep getting the damn exception "read failed, or closed Might socket timeout, read ret -1" so I'm trying this aproach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples for bluetoothSocket over at [programcreek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket) which I'm sure are worth looking at rather than starting from a post.

as a side note, have you tried utilising any of the other existing libraries, for example at socket.io? [libraries](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=bluetooth&languages=JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look.