# Find Paired Devices in Range - not finding all devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to find all devices that are paired and are in range of my mobile device.

I'm testing with my laptop and my sony amp which are bluetooth enabled.

I can find my laptop, but my amp always returns "read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1".  My laptop is connected to my amp via bluetooth playing spotify - so  maybe this is why my phone can't connect. However I still need to be able to detect whether this device is in range regardless of whether I can connect to it.

Here is some example code showing how I am trying to retrieve the devices. I got this solution from this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647197/400320

```
 Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = new HashSet<>(getBondedDevices());
    Set<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices = new HashSet<>();
    for (BluetoothDevice device : bondedDevices) {
        BluetoothDevice actual = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
        UUID SERIAL_UUID = actual.getUuids()[0].getUuid(); //if you don't know the UUID of the bluetooth device service, you can get it like this from android cache

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", "Error creating socket");
        }

        try {
            socket.connect();
            connectedDevices.add(device);
            Log.e("", "Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            try {
                Log.e("", "trying fallback...");

                socket = (BluetoothSocket) actual.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(actual, 1);
                socket.connect();
                connectedDevices.add(device);
                Log.e("", "Connected");
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                Log.e("", "Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection!");
            }
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return connectedDevices;
```

Comment: It's likely that your amp doesn't offer serial communication over bluetooth.

Comment: What does that mean? My phone has also previously been paired with my amp as well as my laptop

Comment: It's really out of the scope of comments, but Bluetooth offers different service profiles. Your amplifier is likely an audio-device, so it offers A2DP. If you're opening an rfcomm socket, it would look for an SPP profile, which your amp may or may not have. Thus, connection refused.

Comment: In that case, Is there an alternative way I can ascertain that it is in range? Feel free to answer as an answer rarther than a comment :)