# Bluetooth connect failed. java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

This question confused me for a long time. I had seen all kinds of solutions,including [IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3/18786701#18786701) , but all not work.

Main ideas:
1. bond the device;
2. create a socket by uuid;
3. cancelDiscovery and connect.

The log list is as follows:

```
04-14 11:12:53.044: W/BluetoothAdapter(22212): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
04-14 11:12:53.044: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CA_ErtmConnectReq()  PSM: 0x0001  BDA: dc2c2600006c  p_ertm_info: 0x00000000 allowed:0x0 preferred:0
04-14 11:12:53.044: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CLOSED evt: 21
04-14 11:12:53.044: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CLOSED evt: 7
04-14 11:12:53.064: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: W4_L2CAP_CON_RSP evt: 11
04-14 11:12:53.064: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CONFIG evt: 24
04-14 11:12:53.074: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CONFIG evt: 14
04-14 11:12:53.074: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CONFIG evt: 25
04-14 11:12:53.074: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: CONFIG evt: 15
04-14 11:12:53.264: W/bt-sdp(2445): process_service_search_attr_rsp
04-14 11:12:53.264: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CA_DisconnectReq()  CID: 0x004a
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/bt-l2cap(2445): L2CAP - st: W4_L2CAP_DISC_RSP evt: 18
04-14 11:12:53.274: E/bt-btif(2445): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:91, failed to find channle,                                       status:1, scn:0
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/bt-btif(2445): invalid rfc slot id: 91
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:574)
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:585)
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:326)
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at com.wormhole.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity$ListItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:152)
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-14 11:12:53.274: W/System.err(22212):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1115)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3691)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
04-14 11:12:53.284: W/System.err(22212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 11:12:53.294: W/System.err(22212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 11:12:53.294: W/System.err(22212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-14 11:12:53.294: W/System.err(22212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
04-14 11:12:53.294: W/System.err(22212):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Other information:
Master device is my phone(android 4.4.4 or android 5.1.1), and slave device is a HID device, UUID is "00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

Thanks for all if could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation，the bluetooth settings that comes with the system works.

So, I look the source code of the bluetooth settings.

And Copy the lib`frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/bluetooth` into my project.

Use reflect to invoke the hide Class and function or variable.

Finally, it works.

I wish this could help.

Comment: Same problem here. Can you share the solution? Every try of to connect using the reflected methods I've found didn't work too =/

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
 private void connect(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        try {
            int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (sdk >= 10) {
                mBluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BltContant.SPP_UUID);
            } else {
                mBluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BltContant.SPP_UUID);
            }
            if (mBluetoothSocket != null) {
                APP.bluetoothSocket = mBluetoothSocket;
                if (bluetoothadapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    bluetoothadapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                if (!mBluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
                    mBluetoothSocket.connect();
                }
                //EventBus.getDefault().post(new BluRxBean(connectsuccess, bluetoothDevice));
            }
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
                mBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(bluetoothDevice, 1);
                mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("BLUE", e.toString());
                try {
                    mBluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```