# Bluetooth dual mode device connection failure, "java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1"

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth dual-mode device (Bluetooth classic + BLE). From my Android phone, I connect to the BLE interface through `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()` method, and to the Bluetooth Classic interface like

```
socket = bluetoothdevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
socket.connect();
```

If I connect to Bluetooth Classic first and then BLE, things work normally. But if I connect to BLE first and then Bluetooth Classic, I cannot connect to the Bluetooth socket, resulting in error:

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1

I tried the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647197/1527875) but it didn't help in my case.