# How to connect to OBDII via Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

Currently I've been using this reference http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development but I am still confused on what the next steps are for my Android app to be able to connect to the OBDII. I found code online for a simple bluetooth app. The app is able to form bluetooth connections with other Android phones but not with the OBDII.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
private BluetoothAdapter BA;
private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

public void on(View v) {
    if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void off(View v) {
    BA.disable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void visible(View v) {
    Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
}

public void list(View v) {
    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Moving forward, what must be done in order for the app to be able to successfully establish and maintain a bluetooth connection with the OBDII.

Comment: Have you solution for this . I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check [android-obd-reader](https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader) OBDII example, which helps you to connect OBDII with your device.

It is using [OBD-II Java API](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) to connect and read data from obd.

Using below classes you can manage connection and read data from obd.

[BluetoothManager.java](https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pires/obd/reader/io/BluetoothManager.java) : It's helps you to connect device

```
public class BluetoothManager {

private static final String TAG = BluetoothManager.class.getName();
/*
 * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html
 * #createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)
 *
 * "Hint: If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the
 * well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. However if you
 * are connecting to an Android peer then please generate your own unique
 * UUID."
 */
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

/**
 * Instantiates a BluetoothSocket for the remote device and connects it.
 * <p/>
 * See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3/18786701#18786701
 *
 * @param dev The remote device to connect to
 * @return The BluetoothSocket
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static BluetoothSocket connect(BluetoothDevice dev) throws IOException {
    BluetoothSocket sock = null;
    BluetoothSocket sockFallback = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Bluetooth connection..");
    try {
        sock = dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        sock.connect();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection. Falling back..", e1);
        Class<?> clazz = sock.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{Integer.TYPE};
        try {
            Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
            Object[] params = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)};
            sockFallback = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(sock.getRemoteDevice(), params);
            sockFallback.connect();
            sock = sockFallback;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't fallback while establishing Bluetooth connection.", e2);
            throw new IOException(e2.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return sock;
}
}
```

[ObdGatewayService.java](https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pires/obd/reader/io/ObdGatewayService.java) : It have connection code and reading data from obd.

```
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.EchoOffCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.LineFeedOffCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.ObdResetCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.SelectProtocolCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.TimeoutCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.commands.temperature.AmbientAirTemperatureCommand;
import com.github.pires.obd.enums.ObdProtocols;
import com.github.pires.obd.exceptions.UnsupportedCommandException;
import com.github.pires.obd.reader.R;
import com.github.pires.obd.reader.activity.ConfigActivity;
import com.github.pires.obd.reader.activity.MainActivity;
import com.github.pires.obd.reader.io.ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This service is primarily responsible for establishing and maintaining a
 * permanent connection between the device where the application runs and a more
 * OBD Bluetooth interface.
 * <p/>
 * Secondarily, it will serve as a repository of ObdCommandJobs and at the same
 * time the application state-machine.
 */
public class ObdGatewayService extends AbstractGatewayService {

    private static final String TAG = ObdGatewayService.class.getName();
    @Inject
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    private BluetoothDevice dev = null;
    private BluetoothSocket sock = null;

    public void startService() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting service..");

        // get the remote Bluetooth device
        final String remoteDevice = prefs.getString(ConfigActivity.BLUETOOTH_LIST_KEY, null);
        if (remoteDevice == null || "".equals(remoteDevice)) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.text_bluetooth_nodevice), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // log error
            Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth device has been selected.");

            // TODO kill this service gracefully
            stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        } else {

            final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            dev = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(remoteDevice);


    /*
     * Establish Bluetooth connection
     *
     * Because discovery is a heavyweight procedure for the Bluetooth adapter,
     * this method should always be called before attempting to connect to a
     * remote device with connect(). Discovery is not managed by the Activity,
     * but is run as a system service, so an application should always call
     * cancel discovery even if it did not directly request a discovery, just to
     * be sure. If Bluetooth state is not STATE_ON, this API will return false.
     *
     * see
     * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter
     * .html#cancelDiscovery()
     */
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Bluetooth discovery.");
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            showNotification(getString(R.string.notification_action), getString(R.string.service_starting), R.drawable.ic_btcar, true, true, false);

            try {
                startObdConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "There was an error while establishing connection. -> "
                                + e.getMessage()
                );

                // in case of failure, stop this service.
                stopService();
                throw new IOException();
            }
            showNotification(getString(R.string.notification_action), getString(R.string.service_started), R.drawable.ic_btcar, true, true, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start and configure the connection to the OBD interface.
     * <p/>
     * See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3/18786701#18786701
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void startObdConnection() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting OBD connection..");
        isRunning = true;
        try {
            sock = BluetoothManager.connect(dev);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection. Stopping app..", e2);
            stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        }

        // Let's configure the connection.
        Log.d(TAG, "Queueing jobs for connection configuration..");
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new ObdResetCommand()));

        //Below is to give the adapter enough time to reset before sending the commands, otherwise the first startup commands could be ignored.
        try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new EchoOffCommand()));

    /*
     * Will send second-time based on tests.
     *
     * TODO this can be done w/o having to queue jobs by just issuing
     * command.run(), command.getResult() and validate the result.
     */
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new EchoOffCommand()));
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new LineFeedOffCommand()));
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new TimeoutCommand(62)));

        // Get protocol from preferences
        final String protocol = prefs.getString(ConfigActivity.PROTOCOLS_LIST_KEY, "AUTO");
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.valueOf(protocol))));

        // Job for returning dummy data
        queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new AmbientAirTemperatureCommand()));

        queueCounter = 0L;
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization jobs queued.");


    }

    /**
     * This method will add a job to the queue while setting its ID to the
     * internal queue counter.
     *
     * @param job the job to queue.
     */
    @Override
    public void queueJob(ObdCommandJob job) {
        // This is a good place to enforce the imperial units option
        job.getCommand().useImperialUnits(prefs.getBoolean(ConfigActivity.IMPERIAL_UNITS_KEY, false));

        // Now we can pass it along
        super.queueJob(job);
    }

    /**
     * Runs the queue until the service is stopped
     */
    protected void executeQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Executing queue..");
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            ObdCommandJob job = null;
            try {
                job = jobsQueue.take();

                // log job
                Log.d(TAG, "Taking job[" + job.getId() + "] from queue..");

                if (job.getState().equals(ObdCommandJobState.NEW)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Job state is NEW. Run it..");
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.RUNNING);
                    if (sock.isConnected()) {
                        job.getCommand().run(sock.getInputStream(), sock.getOutputStream());
                    } else {
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Can't run command on a closed socket.");
                    }
                } else
                    // log not new job
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "Job state was not new, so it shouldn't be in queue. BUG ALERT!");
            } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (UnsupportedCommandException u) {
                if (job != null) {
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.NOT_SUPPORTED);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Command not supported. -> " + u.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException io) {
                if (job != null) {
                    if(io.getMessage().contains("Broken pipe"))
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.BROKEN_PIPE);
                    else
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "IO error. -> " + io.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (job != null) {
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to run command. -> " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (job != null) {
                final ObdCommandJob job2 = job;
                ((MainActivity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((MainActivity) ctx).stateUpdate(job2);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop OBD connection and queue processing.
     */
    public void stopService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping service..");

        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        jobsQueue.clear();
        isRunning = false;

        if (sock != null)
            // close socket
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

        // kill service
        stopSelf();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public static void saveLogcatToFile(Context context, String devemail) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{devemail});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "OBD2 Reader Debug Logs");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\nManufacturer: ").append(Build.MANUFACTURER);
        sb.append("\nModel: ").append(Build.MODEL);
        sb.append("\nRelease: ").append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());

        String fileName = "OBDReader_logcat_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "OBD2Logs");
        if (dir.mkdirs()) {
            File outputFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            Log.d("savingFile", "Going to save logcat to " + outputFile);
            //emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it helps you. Please leave comment or edit your question if more help require.