# making bluetooth connection with other device

Tags: android

I'm facing problem when trying to connect to other devices on my android app

the devices are shown on a list but i can't make connection from my application!

here is the code for that:

bluetooth.java:

```
package com.csp.carservices;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {


private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("59b4fb6c-5c46-4867-93fc-f46e072f3b87");

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            adapter.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                    + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
        }
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private Button dis;
private ListView listview;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private static final int ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
private static final int DISCOVERABLE_DURATION = 300;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);


    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String  itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
            // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
            ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
            t.start();

        }
    });

}




public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    adapter.clear();

    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view;

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oop! Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {

        if (toggleButton.isChecked()){ // to turn on bluetooth
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // A dialog will appear requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth
                Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device has already been enabled." +
                                "\n" + "Scanning for remote Bluetooth devices...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
                discoverDevices();
                // Make local device discoverable by other devices
                makeDiscoverable();

                ListeningThread t = new ListeningThread();
                t.start();


            }
        } else { // Turn off bluetooth

            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            adapter.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is now disabled.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE) {

        // Bluetooth successfully enabled!
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha! Bluetooth is now enabled." +
                            "\n" + "Scanning for remote Bluetooth devices...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Make local device discoverable by other devices
            makeDiscoverable();

            // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
            discoverDevices();

        } else { // RESULT_CANCELED as user refused or failed to enable Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not enabled.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Turn off togglebutton
            toggleButton.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE){

        if (resultCode == DISCOVERABLE_DURATION){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is now discoverable by other devices for " +
                            DISCOVERABLE_DURATION + " seconds",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to enable discoverability on your device.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

protected void discoverDevices(){

    // To scan for remote Bluetooth devices
    if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovering other bluetooth devices...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery failed to start.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void makeDiscoverable(){
    // Make local device discoverable
    Intent discoverableIntent = new
            Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVERABLE_DURATION);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bluetooth, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class ListeningThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;

    public ListeningThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket temp = null;
        try {
            temp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(getString(R.string.app_name), uuid);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothServerSocket = temp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        // This will block while listening until a BluetoothSocket is returned
        // or an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection is accepted
            if (bluetoothSocket != null) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A connection has been accepted.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
               /*
                   manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
               */

                try {
                    bluetoothServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Cancel the listening socket and terminate the thread
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


    public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket temp = null;
        bluetoothDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothSocket = temp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery as it will slow down the connection
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
        /*
           manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
        */
    }

    // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

activity_bluetooth.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.csp.carservices.Bluetooth">
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:textOn="Bluetooth On"
    android:textOff="Bluetooth Off"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace in case you are getting any exceptions ?

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:687)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:699)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:376)
W/System.err:     at com.csp.carservices.Bluetooth$ConnectingThread.run(Bluetooth.java:315)

Comment: I think you should follow this link, some one has already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3