# Bluetooth Code to send string In Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have got list of paired devices of Bluetooth.Now i want to send text to that particular paired device.I have done code for that.

Below is the code:

```
private void init() throws IOException {
BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (blueAdapter != null) {
    if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if(bondedDevices.size() > 0) {
            Object[] devices = (Object []) bondedDevices.toArray();
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) devices[position];
            ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
            BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
            socket.connect();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        }

        Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
    } else {
        Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
    }
}
}

public void write(String s) throws IOException {
outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}

public void run() {
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytes = 0;
int b = BUFFER_SIZE;

while (true) {
    try {
        bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But i'm getting these Error:

```
 java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read      ret: -1
 04-05 10:53:41.356 5580-5580/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:900)
 04-05 10:53:41.356 5580-5580/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:912)
 04-05 10:53:41.356 5580-5580/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:531)
```

So, please help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3)

Comment: No i'm running on marshmallow so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of device are you trying to connect to?

-> Based on discussion: If trying to connect to another phone running Android there must be application which is accepting the connection. Working example is available from Google: [BluetoothChat](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

---

You can try speeding up the connection process:

```
// Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
```

Or you can try using different UUID (are there more supported)?

```
System.out.println(uuids);
```

Or you can try using insecure connection:

```
device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...)
```

BTW: Your code for reading data from inpust stream won't work very well. Take a look at example from Google Chat Application: [BluetoothChatService](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html)

Comment: I have tried all this suggestion but still facing same error

Comment: Is it possible that there is already another active connection so the device is refusing additional ones? What kind of bluetooth device is that? Does is support serial communication (SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB)?

Comment: I have Galaxy On5 Pro and i have try this uuid also but it's not working.

Comment: What kind of BT device is the paired one - the one you are trying to connect to.

Comment: lenovo k3 note or motorola g4

Comment: So you are trying to connect two different Android Phones? Is there an application accepting BT connections on one of them? What about testing the connection with https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html?

Comment: i have downloaded this code but it also gives me same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139960/discussion-between-mansi-bhatt-and-petr-sabata).