# Bluetooth Connection to Raspberry Pi 3: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I am new to Android and have been working through a [tutorial](http://mcuhq.com/27/simple-android-bluetooth-application-with-arduino-example) to get a basic Android application set up that can connect via Bluetooth to a Raspberry Pi 3. I am testing the application using Android 7.0 (Nougat), but am getting an exception when trying to connect:

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

This seems to be a fairly common exception, and I have tried many suggestions to fix it, but to no avail.

The error is occuring in my `Thread` class.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        boolean fail = false;

        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            bluetoothSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            fail = true;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
        } catch(IOException e){
            try {
//                            // fallback method for android >= 4.2
                bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket)device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", UUID.class).invoke(device, BTMODULEUUID);

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e2){
                    try{
                        fail = true;
                        bluetoothSocket.close();
                        handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1).sendToTarget();
                    } catch (IOException e3){
                        //@Todo Insert code to handle this
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e2){
                //@Todo Insert code to handle this
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e2){
                //@Todo Insert code to handle this
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e2){
                //@Todo Insert code to handle this
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        if(fail == false){
            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
            connectedThread.start();

            handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1, name).sendToTarget();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

The code utilizes the fallback for Android >= 4.2, and then catches the exception when it tries to connect.

The rest of my code is the same as the tutorial, but I can post more if needed.

---

**UPDATE:**

This has been marked a duplicate of this question: [IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3)

I have tried that solution, and receive the same error.

```
bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket)device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE}).invoke(device, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)});
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate question since this workaround will not work for Nougat 7.0. Google has confirmed and fixed this bug in 7.1 patches.

Comment: @KH_AJU Can you post a link for google confirming about this bug.

Comment: @SandeepR Link to official Nexus forum regarding this bug **https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/rz3BGwI-BDA**