# Data transmission between arduino and android over bluetooth. Problem with NPE

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I should transfer some Strings to arduino. Just only pass, do not take anything.
This my code. I'm working with android and kotlin for the first time.

```
class Validation : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var mmOutputStream: OutputStream
lateinit var mmSocket: BluetoothSocket

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_validation)


    resolve_Btn.setOnClickListener {bluetoothAdd() }


}

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
private fun bluetoothAdd() {
    val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth

        Log.e("Bluetooth ", "not found")
    }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
        val pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                mmSocket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
                mmSocket.connect()
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket.outputStream
                val message = "aaa"
                val msgBuffer = message.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                mmOutputStream.write(msgBuffer)
                Log.e("Mac Addressess", "are:  " + mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.address))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now when I added mmSocket!!.connect(), I catch this

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
>        Caused by: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
>           at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:706)
>           at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:718)
>           at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:384)
>           at com.example.nikita.vas.Validation.bluetoothAdd(Validation.kt:52)
>           at com.example.nikita.vas.Validation.access$bluetoothAdd(Validation.kt:21)
>           at com.example.nikita.vas.Validation$onCreate$1.onClick(Validation.kt:30)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `mmSocket.connect()` before accessing `outputStream` object.
Try this:

```
 mmSocket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( 
                    UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
                    mmSocket.connect()
                    mmOutputStream = mmSocket!!.outputStream
                    val message = "aaa"
                    val msgBuffer = message.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                    mmOutputStream!!.write(msgBuffer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But now I have another problem: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)    When i try call mmSocket!!.connect()

Comment: In the log of error must seen line cause error in you code. Please attach full stack-trace here.

Comment: I looked at your stacktrace. Look there, maybe this is answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3