# Communicate between two (and more) Flutter applications using flutter_bluetooth_serial

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, flutter-packages

I'm developing Flutter app for Android, where I want to exchange some data between few instances of my app on different devices via Bluetooth. I'm using [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) package (this is the only package I found which supports Bluetooth Classic, not Bluetooth Low Energy). I'm able to make connection
between device 1 and device 2 using `BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address);` (but even there was a problem, I had to modify the plugin and apply [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786701/4645312) to make connection work).

Now I want to run my app on device 2 (which is connected with device 1) and send or receive some data, but I have no idea how I can do that using **flutter_bluetooth_serial**. In device 1 where I create connection I can use result of `BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address)` to send or listen for some data, but on device 2 I can't use it, because connection is already established by device 1 and I can't see another API for communication.

To simplify: let's say I want to achieve something more or less like Bluetooth chat functionality in [this example application](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/tree/master/example), but between multiple Flutter applications, not Flutter app and raspberry pi.
Is there any way of solving it with use of **flutter_bluetooth_serial** or any other package? Or I have to write some native Android code?

Comment: Hi Lisla, have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @Danilo, kind of. I've modified the plugin to use [BluetoothServerSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket). Thanks to it, when device 1 connects to device 2, on device 2 I can listen for that connection and receive a BluetoothSocket to manage connection.

Comment: Hi, @LislaV can u elaborate ur solution?