# Android Bluetooth RFCOMM connection failing, getUUIDS() returns no SPP UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send data using Bluetooth Classic between two paired Android devices.

One device is Huawei P Smart 2019 with EMUI Android 10, the other one a Pixel 4a running Calyx OS Android 11.

If I use the default `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` UUID for a SPP / RFCOMM connection, it fails with `read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1` on both secure and insecure connection attempts.
The paired device's  `BluetoothDevice#getUUIDs()` only returns (on both ends)

```
0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

`00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` (= SPP UUID) is nowhere to be found.

Some UUIDs (like `0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` in the list work for connection (no error), however sending data does not work and gives no exception on both ends.

I also tried to use the reflection port workaround described in other issues, but no result ([IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3))

Does one Android device simply not support SPP / RFCOMM or why does it not connect using the SPP UUID (1101)?