# How can I connect to a bluetooth device in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-jetpack

I'm trying to connect to a device via uuid on Android, but I always get `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`, I tried making a function: https://hastebin.com/foyihajeqa.kotlin but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try with this way,

```
object BluetoothManager {
    var device: BluetoothDevice? = null
    var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
    fun set(device: BluetoothDevice) {
        BluetoothManager.device = null
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket!!.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            socket = null
        }
        BluetoothManager.device = device
        try {
            //UUID of the target device
            val uuid: UUID = UUID.fromString("00000001-0000-1000-8000-22305F9B34FB")
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("bt socket", "IOException")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same error, didn't fix

Comment: see this, its might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3/18786701#18786701